# How to get average value for each hourly increment that is split into 5 minute intervals

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have an AWS Redshift table that looks like this:

| interval_date | interval_time | power | on_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:00 | 2.65 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:05 | 3.92 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:10 | 2.05 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:15 | 1.85 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:20 | 5.92 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:25 | 7.52 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:30 | 9.84 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:35 | 6.84 | N |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:40 | 5.01 | N |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:45 | 4.70 | N |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:50 | 8.57 | N |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:55 | 1.94 | N |
| 2022-05-01 | 01:00 | 3.87 | Y |

The table continues with more timestamps going all the way until 11:55 PM for any given day up to the current day/time. I am trying to get the average value of `power` for each hourly interval (so the average for 12 AM should be the values from the previous day (4/30/2022) at 23:05 to current day (5/1/2022) at 00:00, 1 AM is 00:05 to 01:00, 2 AM is 01:05 to 02:00, etc) where the `on_status` equals `Y`.

I have a basic query that gets me the average for a whole day (for context, the interval_date would be parameterized).

```
SELECT AVG(power)
FROM table
WHERE on_status = 'Y'
  AND interval_date = '2022-05-01';
```

I am unsure how to partition the `interval_time` column so that the values are averaged hourly. An idea of the final result I am looking for is:

| interval_date | interval_time | power | on_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 00:00 | 2.65 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 01:00 | 5.00 | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 02:00 | X | Y |
| 2022-05-01 | 03:00 | X | Y |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the type for interval_time, so I'm assuming a string, you can parse it out with a case statement like this:

```
SELECT interval_date,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(interval_time,4,2)='00' THEN interval_time
            WHEN SUBSTRING(interval_time,1,2)='23' THEN '00:00'
            ELSE FORMAT(convert(int,SUBSTRING(interval_time,1,2))+1,'00')+':00'
       END interval_time,
       AVG(power)
 FROM mytable
WHERE on_status = 'Y'
GROUP BY interval_date,
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(interval_time,4,2)='00' THEN interval_time
            WHEN SUBSTRING(interval_time,1,2)='23' THEN '00:00'
            ELSE FORMAT(convert(int,SUBSTRING(interval_time,1,2))+1,'00')+':00'
       END
```

Note that to get your target of 5.17, I had to comment out the on_status = 'Y' filter.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b604e4fe6696465aac75676e69b92a47

Comment: that query is a great start! `FORMAT` does not exist in AWS Redshift so I had to modify the `ELSE` case to this: `ELSE TRIM(TO_CHAR(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(interval_time, 1, 2)) + 1, '09') + ':00')`. The only requirement this query misses is to average in the previous day's power starting at 23:05 going to midnight of current day. In this example, I'd expect three rows only, one for 2022-04-30 23:00 8.62, one for 2022-05-01 00:00 4.17, and 2022-05-01 01:00 4.99. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8fd90a954e4b51ca1b8b4326716399aa

Comment: Whoops, what's happening is that when it's 23:?? and not 23:00, it's using the date to aggregate, where it needs ot move to date + 1.

Comment: Updated DbFiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=692efb2e9332b736c1fa50e9d2bbce9b  Note that I don't know if DATEADD is supported in AWS Redshift, so you'll need to use whatever function is supported there.

Comment: Your improvements worked. I noticed that to filter on by date (`interval_date = '2022-05-01'`) would cause issues with the 00:00 timestamps which makes sense. I added to my `WHERE` clause `interval_date >= @someDate` where `@someDate` is my variable and I would pass in the date I needed data for minus one day, then in my code I ignored or removed the data I did not need. Thanks for your help.